# Code Output Comparison and Correction Request

Tags: java, arrays, class

> > **[the task description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBgvQ.png)**

```java
class Solution {

    /**
     * @param n the given positive number
     * @return the square matrix of order n according to the given pattern
     */
    public static int[][] create(int n) {
        int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == n - 1 || j == 0 || j == n - 1) {
                    matrix[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return matrix;
    }

    // Helper method to print the matrix
    public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test cases
        int[][] result1 = create(5);
        printMatrix(result1);

        int[][] result2 = create(6);
        printMatrix(result2);

        int[][] result3 = create(1);
        printMatrix(result3);

        int[][] result4 = create(2);
        printMatrix(result4);
    }
}
```

Hi everyone,

When I test the code above, it outputs like this:

**Unexpected Output**

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1


1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1


1


1 1
1 1
```

**However**, there are some issues in my code for outputting the correct version of the visibility. It should output like this:

**Expected Output**

```
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 1


1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 1


1


1 1
1 1
```

And to others, it is correctly outputted.

So how can i output it correctly. **Any ideas?**

I attempted to run the provided code for visibility calculations. I expected the output to accurately represent the visibility matrix for each scenario. However, upon reviewing the results, I noticed discrepancies in the visibility values. The correct visibility matrix for each case should follow a specific pattern, and I am seeking assistance in identifying and correcting the issues in the code that lead to the incorrect output.

[My portfolio](https://42yuarzibekov.me)
If you want to contact.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. To better understand how to use this site, it might help to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and visit links in those resources. In particular, please describe what the program is supposed to do. Those who would help want to compare your code to the description. Providing a description makes it easier to tell what is a bug and what is intended.

Comment: The source of this question appears to be from a programming practice / challenge / site. Can you, please, provide a link to the page to the source? Thanks.

Comment: There are now two answers, which I did not see at the time I posted my first comment. Note that these the examples output of the answers disagree. That supports the point in the second part of my first comment: You need to provide a description of what is wanted.  Examples without explanation are sometimes misunderstood.

Comment: It's an improvement. But, in my opinion, it would help to add a description about what the program should do.

Comment: **Hello**, @OldDogProgrammer How is it now? Is it understandable? because i can't see it.

Comment: Can you see that I mentioned your username?

Comment: You need to tell us what the "specific pattern" is.

Comment: Yes. When you use @OldDogProgrammer in your comment, a red dot appears with my "in box" icon.

Comment: It looks like one of the answers does produce output that matches the "expected results", while the other answer does not.

Comment: Yes it is. Some improvements should be made. It outputs the expected result in reverse

Comment: That's the result of differences in the test driver, which is unimportant here. You can replace the `main` method in the answer with the `main` method in your code.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer, now you can see the task description above the question. There is a link for viewing the description.

Comment: I apologize. I thought there must be text that describes the pattern. It looks like there isn't. You really are expected to infer the pattern from examples.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```java
public static int[][] create(int size) {
    int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];

    for (int colLo = 0, colHi = size - 1; colLo <= colHi; colLo++, colHi--) {
        for (int rowLo = colLo, rowHi = colHi; rowLo <= rowHi; rowLo++, rowHi--) {
            matrix[rowLo][colLo] = 1;    matrix[rowLo][colHi] = 1;
            matrix[rowHi][colLo] = 1;    matrix[rowHi][colHi] = 1;
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
            if (col > 0)
                System.out.print(' ');
            System.out.print(matrix[row][col]);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    for (int size = 1; size < 7; size++) {
        printMatrix(create(size));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1

1 1
1 1

1 0 1
1 1 1
1 0 1

1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1

1 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 1

1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
```